# Posterior of risk ratio as ratio of samples from posteriors of risks

Tags: distributions, bayesian, estimation, posterior, relative-risk

I want to sample from the posterior distribution of a risk ratio. My idea is:

- define the posterior of risks $R_A$ and $R_B$) for two subgroups (e.g, exposed and non-exposed) in my data, using Beta(1.1, 1.1) as prior.
- draw samples from the posterior distribution of the two parameters and take $RR = R_A/R_B$.

Is it correct? Furthermore, can I consider the draws from the two groups independent given the data? (useful for practical reasons since only one loop is needed).